# How do I check if my uninitialized variable is of type List?

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

I have the following class definition:

```
[ActionsClass[typeof(MyActions)]
public class NkProject
    {
        int ProjectId;
        IList<NkItem> Items;
        NkItem SingleItem;
    }
```

The class mostly contains only fields, with the class attribute stating which class is responsible for "handling" this class as part of a larger framework.

Using reflection, I parse this file to generate some meta data and I'd like to know if "Items" is of type List (or any type of collection which acts as a list) but everything I've tried so far fails. I'm iterating over an array of `FieldInfo[]` objects.

1. Check for `IEnumerable`:

   ```
   if(field.FieldType.GetInterface("IEnumerable") != null)
   ```

   This also detects strings as IEnumerables, which is incorrect. I'd prefer if strings fail to pass this check and get treated as primitives in a sense (the `else` of the above `if`).
2. Changed above to: `if(field is ICollection)` and that also fails.
3. Changed above to: `if(field is IList && field.GetType().IsGenericType)` and it still fails to be detected correctly.

Is there a way to look only at the type of the variable references to ascertain whether `Items` is of type List and a parallel check for `string Items` fails? I'm guessing #2 and #3 above fail because `Items` is not an object and thus there isn't any inheritance information attached to it. I could be wrong, but I think that's what is happening. A `field.GetType().Name` returns the type as IList`1. Not sure how to get around this.

**EDIT/UPDATE**: If the above check fails, and a string goes through, the output meta is incorrectly formatted. Since, if it's a collection/list of items, I need to fetch further metadata for them (via the appropriately set attributes). This step is only executed if the variable is of type List/Collection but not if it's a single reference or a primitive.

**Reflection code:**

```
foreach (var field in fieldInfo)
{
    Property property;

    //If it's a collection field, get the appropriate collection name as set in its attribute
    if (field.FieldType.GetInterface("IEnumerable") != null) //currently lets strings pass through too.
    {
        //Get the type of the "type argument" of the IEnumerable
        Type[] typeArgs = field.FieldType.GetGenericArguments();
        //Get the collection name for that type to use in the XML
        MyAttribute att = (MyAttribute )Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(typeArgs[0], typeof(MyAttribute ));

        if (att == null)
            throw new ArgumentException("Using collection: {0} in Your class: {1}. Collection must have MyAttribute[Collection=\"\"] attribute defined on its class declaration.");

        else
        {   
         //do something with meta data          
        }
    }

    //If non-collection, possibly primitive field do something else
    else
    {
        //do other stuff here.
    }
}
```

Comment: You are trying to do this before you set the value of `Items` anywhere (aka, its currently == null)?

Comment: Yes. As I said, I need to parse this class definition to pull out meta information. I don't have any object set in Items.

Comment: Without seeing your reflection code, I'm guessing `field` is a `FieldInfo` object, which will never be anything other than a `FieldInfo` object, so you can't compare it using `field is XXXX`... `field.GetType()` will also return a `FieldInfo` type, you probably want `field.FieldType`

Comment: `IList``1` (forgive extra backtick) is the .NET name for `IList < >` if this is the interface you want to be looking for then look for that interface.  You'll need to look at the generic type definition, though, as Alistair suggests for `List < >`

Comment: `IList<T>` does not derive from `IList`, so checking for `IList` not going to help. Something like `typeof(IList<NkItem>).IsAssignableFrom(field.FieldType)` should work.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov that requires specifying the type argument, which is probably not possible, assuming the function must be able to recognize lists of other types of objects, too.

Comment: @phoog Digging through the type to figure out that it is `IList<>` of some particular type is possible (manually checking for `IAssignableFrom`), but I'm not completely sure what OP is looking for as clearly `field.GetType()` should NRE if indeed it is not initialized. Lack of complete sample is unfortunate. And msmolcic just posted the way to build `IList<runtime type of element>`.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov `field` is not uninitialized; it is a FieldInfo.  The field it defines is, however, null.  As others have noted, it should be `field.FieldType`.  Also I would get the list of interfaces and check the generic ones for their type definitions.  Is AssignableFrom preferable for some reason?  Plus msmolcic's answer has problems of its own.

Comment: @RonBeyer - Added reflection code for clarification.

Comment: *"This also detects strings as IEnumerables, which is incorrect"* Just FYI, strings are `IEnumerable` (think `foreach (char c in "this string") { ... }`). I think your answers cover it pretty clearly but its hard to tell why you need reflection before you have an initialized field, before its initialized the field is an `IList<NkItem>`. Are you trying to do some kind of custom serialization?

Comment: one more note: Do you care about `MyListX : MyOtherType<T> : EvenMore : IList<int>` or you *only* care about immediate `IList<X>`?

Comment: @RonBeyer - Yes. That is correct - I am looking into custom serializability in a sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the generic type information to check whether it is a List

```
if(field.FieldType.IsGenericType 
    && field.FieldType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(List<>))
```

currently I have the following function in my code base for this type of situation.

```
public static bool Closes(this Type type, Type openType)
{
    if (type == null)
        return false;

    if (type.IsGenericType && type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == openType) return true;

    foreach (var @interface in type.GetInterfaces())
    {
        if (@interface.Closes(openType)) return true;
    }

    return type.BaseType.Closes(openType);
}
```

this would allow you to just call

```
field.FieldType.Closes(typeof(List<>)
```

Comment: This generates an exception - `"This operation is only valid on generic types."`

Comment: yeah sorry I forgot to add that guard.   hopefully this is a better answer

Comment: This is a good answer but in the question the field type is `IList < >`.  The answer ought to use that type instead.  It will not give the correct result otherwise.

Comment: @phoog is right. The check fails at run-time if it's `List<>` instead of `IList<>`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this method:

```
public bool IsGenericList(Type type)
{
    if (type == null)
        return false;

    if (!type.IsGenericType)
        return false;

    var genericArguments = type.GetGenericArguments();
    if (genericArguments.Length != 1)
        return false;

    var listType = typeof(IList<>).MakeGenericType(genericArguments);
    return listType.IsAssignableFrom(type);
}
```

Comment: This would fail in the admittedly unlikely case where a type has more than one type parameter but implements the generic IList.